# Renaming file geodatabase and keeping all mxd project linked?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase

I have a big folder (20GB) (with different folders with shapes, rasters and filegeodatabases)

This folder has a orthographic mistake that I would like to correct.

This gdb is involved in a big number of mxd projects so it is quite impossible to replace the path manually.

I have a way to move feature class one by one (and each of them take a lot of time) but this is too much work.

(I use arcgis 10.2)

Anyone has an idea to resolve my issue?

Comment: As said above it is possible to use a script method. One note of cautious though . Are you sure the data is not being used by any other Mxds That are outside the folder you run the script on . If you re point the data to a new guy and then delete the old one . This will cause broken links

Answer (score 4):

You could use python/arcpy for this.

1. Use os.walk method to find all .mxd files within directories/sub directories.
2. Next, iterate through mxd and generate a list of layers (using `for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)`).
3. Use [dataSource](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000) property to list source paths of layers and .find method to find old database name in path string.  Use if conditional logic to evaluate if .find method variable is >-1, if so then use replaceDataSource method in step four.
4. Use [replaceDataSource](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000) method to resource layer to new layer name in gdb.
5. Finally, use `mxd.save()` method to re-save map

This Q/A will give guidance for steps 2-4.

[Repairing data sources in multiple MXDs using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32915/how-do-you-write-a-python-script-for-repairing-data-sources-in-arcgis-10)