# Seeking ArcGIS Pro tool to batch change data sources?

Tags: arcgis-pro, data-source

ArcCatalog has a useful [Set Data Source](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007165) tool which allows for rapidly updating multiple data sources in a map document that have changed.

Is there a similar functionality in ArcGIS Pro for project files, or within a project?

I can presumably also script a solution like [Repairing data sources in multiple MXDs using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32915), but not all our team members have the same skill level.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with ArcPy and a few lines of code.

```py
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'C:\Projects\YosemiteNP\Yosemite.aprx')
aprx.updateConnectionProperties(r'C:\Projects\YosemiteNP\Data\Yosemite.gdb',
                                r'C:\Projects\YosemiteNP\Vector_Data\Yosemite.gdb')
aprx.save()
```

The code above is from [Updating and Fixing Datasets](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm).

Answer (score 1):

For me at least the ArcPy solution didn't work (it ran, but nothing changed).
There is a (rather cumbersome) process using the Catalog View in ArcGIS Pro. It's documented here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/update-data-sources.htm

This only kind of worked for me (3.0.1); my layers remained broken, but then when I fixed one of them manually, the rest all got fixed too.